# How to slide between a CameraActivity and a ListView Activity?

Tags: android, camera, android-activity, slide

I have an activity that displays a camera screen, another one that displays a dynamic list of things, and I would like to slide between them.

The problem is that the ViewPager only allows me to slide between different layouts, without any activity-related effect.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you cannot "slide" between activities

Comment: I think you would want to 'swipe' between activities.

Comment: Where's the code, what have you tried, and where is it failing?

Answer (score 1):

I think that using a ViewPager is what would be the easiest way. But if you don't want to, maybe you can try something like that :

- Code something to detect the swipe gesture.
- When the swipe gesture is detected, start the second activity whith a slide transition.

I've never done something like that. It's just a though.